# Question about Cauchy Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis

show that $f(z)=e^xe^{-iy}$ is not differentiable.

Approach:

$$f(z)=e^xe^{-iy}=e^xe^{(i)(-y)}=e^x(cos(-y)+isin(-y))=e^x(cos(y)-isin(y))$$

$U_x=e^xcos(y),-U_y=sin(y)e^x,V_x=-sin(y)e^x,V_y=-cos(y)e^x$

We can clearly see that $U_x \neq V_y$ and $V_x \neq -U_y$. Is that very clear? or is there a nice way to show that the equalities don't hold?

Comment: It is the simplest way to show f(z) is not holomorphic.

Comment: @Zack Ni One can invoke as well a general rule : as this function writes $f(z)=\overline{\varphi(z)}$ with $\varphi(z)=exp(z)$ holomorphic, $f$ is **not** holomorphic.